# how to scale img by percentage of self and not percentage of its container

Tags: css, image, scaling

how to scale img by percentage of self and not percentage of its container?

I can't believe I never ran into this problem before, so I'm guessing either the standard changed, or I am doing something wrong, because I am pretty sure that back in the day, before CSS even, it was possible to scale an image like this

```
<img src="something.jpg" height="50%" width="50%">
```

but now that scales it by the container objects size, which is totally irrelevant to me.

IS there no other way than for me to start calculating pixels and such in a javascript to achieve this very simple image styling?

If I have an image 500px wide, and the user selects 50%, I want that image to show up 250px wide, I don't care one bit about the size of its container at this moment...

Comment: You need to add `"` after `src`. `src="something.jpg" `

Comment: yea yea, I just wrote an example up, that's not my actual code, nor does the missing " have anything to do with the problem I am having. The scale function works great, only I want to scale to percent of the image, not to percent of the container that the image resides in. But the actual html/css is interpreted correctly by the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it like this (with javascript/jQuery):
-Create a div 
-Insert the image
-pick up the dimension from the image
-set those dimensions to the DIV
-set image dimensions to 100%

That way the image till initially be of original size, my jQuery resize() on the DIV will work and the image will always fill the DIV.

Comment: Hehe, left some info out there - I see in the original question I don't mention that the reason the user can set 50% is that this is an editor where images can be inserted and scaled =) There, now you should be able to follow me a bit better =)

Answer (score 1):

Try the CSS `zoom` property. I believe it works on Chrome, Safari, and IE, but not Firefox.

Comment: Thanks, but that leaves empty white space around the image, it doesn't float together with the text the way an image of the lesser size would if it weren't zoomed down.. I also need total cross-browser-compatibility. Thanks anyways. I ended up just using px width for now with height set to auto, and might work around with some scripting to make the user control percentage and just compute it myself. Still baffeled thought that the functionality isn't there in css3...

Answer (score 0):

img use `style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%;"` will fill up container box but keep all image just inside container.
use `style="min-height:100%;min-width:100%;"` will fill up container and clip if image have different size with container box.

not work for browsers dont support max\min-height\width (below ie7 I think).

Answer (score 0):

Set the percentage size on the image, then use a wrapper around the image with `position: absolute;`

http://jsfiddle.net/KWWZz/

Some unfortunate drawbacks:

1. This doesn't seem to work in IE7 (and as of the time of this posting, jsfiddle doesn't seem to be working for IE7 or IE8, so it's hard to really show that)
2. Because you're using absolute positioning, you'll probably have to alter some parent container's positioning context to get it to work for any given situation.